# XSLT and `foreach`

Tags: xslt

I have the following line of xml that I'm trying transform using XSLT but I'm having trouble. The line is

```
<app>
<lem>text</lem>
<rdg wit="V" type="add.">text1</rdg>
<rdg wit="S" type="add.">text2</rdg>
<rdg wit="SV" type="add.">text3</rdg>
</app>
```

I have several of these `app elements` and then there can be between 1 and 4 `rdg` elements within them, so I'm trying to write a `foreach` statement within a `foreach` statement but it is not working.

I want to say:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tei:app">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="tei:lem"/><xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
        <xsl for-each select="tei:rdg"> <!--I hoping this would loop through each <rdg> within a given <app> element -->
            <xsl:value-of select="//tei:rdg"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="//tei:rdg/@type"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="//tei:rdg/@wit"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But right now this is not working. As it currently stands - this does the right number of loops but for every instance of `rdg` I'm getting the value of the fist `rdg`. But if I remove the double slashes in the three `value-of` elements, then I don't get any values.

Can you spot something I'm doing wrong? Sometimes I get pretty confused about the slash, double slash, no slash use in xpath -- could I be messing up there?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tei:app">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="tei:lem"/><xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
        <xsl for-each select="tei:rdg"> <!--I hoping this would loop through each <rdg> within a given <app> element -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@wit"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In your inner loop your "current()" node is a tei:rdg node. So . access it's contents while @ access the various attributes.

Comment: I do hope that you didn't just use and accept the answer, but also understood what you did wrong and how to avoid the same mistake in future. You need to read about how xsl:for-each sets the context, and about the difference between relative and absolute path expressions.